# Why don't my images and information render on my React localhost?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Recently I started a React course where the chapter goal is to create a monster sort of website. Below I will leave the code of the relevant JS and JSX files. My SearchBox input does appear on my screen, however, the monster images with their respective h2 and p are not appearing only in my react localhost. I have tried going through my code to understand why my code is not working and I haven't been able to find a solution. Here I will leave the link to the API where I am obtaining the images from, you just have to change the number before the ? to access the other images. I am aware that classes are a bit outdated due to hooks but the course is focusing on them initially so that we can understand their behavior, so please do not update the code, just help me with the functionality.

https://robohash.org/1?set=set2&size=180x180

App.js File

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { CardList } from './components/card-list/card-list';
import {SearchBox} from './components/search-box/search-box';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      monsters: [], 
      searchField: ''
    };
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({monsters: users}));
  }

  render() {
    const {monsters, searchField} = this.state;
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(monster => monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())) //This checks if one of the monsters name includes the text inputted into the search field, and filters out those that do not. We lower case it to avoid capital and lower case issues.
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <SearchBox 
          placeholder='Search Monsters'
          handleChange={e => this.setState({searchField: e.target.value})}
        />
        <CardList monsters={filteredMonsters}/> 
      </div> //By using filteredMonsters here, initially all will appear but as we place some input, only those that include the searchField will appear
    )
  }
};

  
export default App;
```

card.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';

export const Card = props => {
    return (
        <div>
        <img src={'https://robohash.org/'+ props.monster.id + '?set=set2&size=180x180'} alt='monster'/>
        <h2> {props.monster.name} </h2>
        <p> {props.monster.email} </p>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

card-list.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card} from '../card/card';
import './card-list.css';

export const CardList = props => {
    return (
    <div className='card-list'>
        {props.monsters.map((monster) => {
            <Card key={monster.id}/>
        })}
    </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Did you check the browser's network tab in the dev tools? It will show which resources it's trying to load and why it fails. Press F12 to see the dev tools, then switch to the network tab and refresh.

Comment: Also, please clarify what exactly you mean by `the monster images with their respective h2 and p are not appearing only in my react localhost`. Are they appearing when you're running the app locally, but not when you move it online? Or the other way around? Also, given Branislav's answer, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with where they're hosted and `props.monster.name` should result in a reference error.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, I used the dev tools to check what was going on, and it's not that the images fail to load because I do not get an error, they simply do not load. They do not appear. About your second comment, what I meant was that neither the image, h2, or p are appearing. They do not appear locally nor online

Comment: The .map() function in your CardList component doesn't return anything. After the arrow you put just the component. If you use a `{ }` block, you need to `return` the JSX inside. Fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisG, now the images and their respective information are working. I do not why the CSS classes are not being applied but I'll fix that on my own. Thank you

Comment: The main <div> in your Card component has no `className` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In `CardList`, you never even passed a `monster` object to your `Card` component. Only a monster id for a key. Basically, you need something like this:

```
<div className='card-list'>
        {props.monsters.map((monster) => {
            <Card key={monster.id} monster={monster} />
        })}
</div>
```

Minor suggestion: Use proper destructuring in `Card` component:

```
export const Card = ({ monster: { id, name, email } }) => {
    return (
        <div>
          <img src={'https://robohash.org/'+ id + '?set=set2&size=180x180'} alt='monster'/>
          <h2> {name} </h2>
          <p> {email} </p>
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-cerf-qcubt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for the feedback regarding destructuring, I will have it in mind for the following projects as well. However, I updated my code to match your initial suggestion regarding the Card component and it still does not work.

Comment: @Aaron_Serpilin I updated my answer with a working Sandbox.

Comment: I just checked it out, I updated the Card component but I am unsure where I have to add the monster constant. I added it to my card-list.jsx file since it used the Card component but I got an error. Where should I add it?